# Android: Show AlertDialog as soon as internet is disconnected

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-alertdialog

I have an application where internet connectivity is must. So, what I want, is that whenever user gets disconnected from Internet (Wifi or Mobile), the `Activity` should be able to detect the network state and should display an `AlertDialog` prompting user to check its connection. I have tried implementing this using broadcast receiver, but my application is getting crashed. Following is the code snippet for the same:

Following code is in `onCreate()` Method

```
  c = this.getApplicationContext();
  broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetWifi = connectivityManager
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        boolean isConnectedMobile = activeNetInfo != null
                && activeNetInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        boolean isConnectedWifi = activeNetWifi != null
                && activeNetWifi.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        AlertDialog alert = alertNoNetwork();
        if (isConnectedMobile || isConnectedWifi) {
            if (alert != null && alert.isShowing()) {
                alert.dismiss();
            }
        } else {
            if (alert != null && !alert.isShowing()) {
                alert.show();
            }
        }

    }

    public AlertDialog alertNoNetwork() {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.err_network_failure_title)
                .setMessage(R.string.err_network_failure_message)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Quit",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            }
                        });
        return builder.create();
    }
};
```

Declaring `c` and `broadcastReceiver` as:

```
private Context c;  
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver ;
```

and registering `broadcastReceiver` in `onResume()` method:

```
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
```

My error logs are:

> 02-25 15:53:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(24768): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } in com.example.ActivityCapturImg$1@1bca6ea7
>   02-25 15:53:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(24768):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:880)
>   02-25 15:53:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(24768):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>   02-25 15:53:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(24768):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   02-25 15:53:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(24768):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>   02-25 15:53:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(24768):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
>   02-25 15:53:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(24768):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   02-25 15:53:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(24768):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   02-25 15:53:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(24768):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
>   02-25 15:53:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(24768):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
>   02-25 15:53:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(24768): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
>   02-25 15:53:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(24768):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:583)
>   02-25 15:53:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(24768):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:272)
>   02-25 15:53:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(24768):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>   02-25 15:53:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(24768):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
>   02-25 15:53:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(24768):    at com.swachhmap.ActivityCapturImg$1.onReceive(ActivityCapturImg.java:235)
>   02-25 15:53:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(24768):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:870)
>   02-25 15:53:35.836: E/AndroidRuntime(24768):    ... 8 more

Kindly help.

Thanks,
Arpit

**EDIT**: `Context c` that is passed in `AlertDialog.Builder` should have been

```
 c = ActivityName.this;
```

instead of `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: You can not show dialog from components other than activity. You need to show Activity-as-dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window --
>   token null is not for an application

Because passing `getApplicationContext()` in `AlertDialog.Builder`

`AlertDialog.Builder` require current active component context instead of application context.

Use Activity context which which calling `Dialog.show()` to create `AlertDialog.Builder` object:

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CurrentActivityName.this);
```

Comment: Thanks, I also figured that out :)